# How to compare $(element).html() == "&times;"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span tag as follows:

`<span>&times;</span>`

In JavaScript, if I check

`$("span").html()`

Response is: `"-"`

Is there any way I can compare

`$("span").html() == "&times;"`

instead of `$("span").html() == "-"`?

Comment: interesting, i've never seen anything like that before

Comment: Response for `&times;` is `×`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an in-memory element and compare it with span

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var dummy = document.createElement('span');
dummy.innerHTML = '&times;'
console.log(span.innerHTML === dummy.innerHTML)
```

```html
<span>&times;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could decode your html Code Back to normal String.

```
var decoded = $('<div>').html('&times;').text();
```

This value should be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

To treat  HTML entities as a string you have to use text() instead of html() method

```
$("span").text() == "&times;"
```

Comment: That does not work. An element's text does not contain any HTML.

Comment: I wonder if your span tag written in this way <span>&times;</span>